# Denodo Jar get conflicts with Play Framework Jar

Tags: java, jar, playframework, apache-commons-codec, denodo

I am using :
Latest version of play framework wi.-> 2.3.5
Latest version of Denodo -> 5.5 win

Denodo is using Apache Common Codec 1.3 whereas Play is using few new methods introduced in Apacahe Common Codec 1.4 (E.g. Caused by: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1Hex(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;`). Somehow denodo's legacy jar is getting preference over play's jar.

Is there any way to get rid of this situation?

Comment: Have you tried using `denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-basic.jar` instead of `denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver.jar`?  The basic jar doesn't have the additional libraries included.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver.jar`, use the `denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-basic.jar`.

From the Denodo Virtual DataPort Developer Guide:

> There are two versions of the JDBC driver to connect to Virtual DataPort (both located in the folder /lib/vdp-jdbcdriver-core/)
>
> 1. denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver.jar (recommended version).
> 2. denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver-basic.jar
>
> Both versions are the same except that the “basic” one does not contain the third-party dependencies required by the driver.